# Percorrer Objeto Json VBA

Tags: json, microsoft-excel, vba

Boa noite,
  estou com dificuldade de percorrer o objeto para obter o resultado de uma 
API

[Objeto a ser percorrido](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl5yi.png)

[image: Erro Apresentadp]

```html
Sub AtualizarJogadores()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Dim Movie As Object
Dim R As Object
Dim scriptControl As Object

Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
scriptControl.Language = "JScript"

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/clubes", False
    .send
    Set R = scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responsetext + ")")
    .abort

        For Each Movie In R





        Next Movie


       End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Já consegui fazer algo do tipo com o exemplo [do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300926/7690982), em que a variável `JsonString`, seria o `.responsetext`

Comment: Obrigado amigo. deu certo

Answer (score -1):

Caso ainda não tenha conseguido segue exemplo:

```
Sub listPokemons()
Dim json As String
Dim jsonObject As Object, item As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objHTTP As Object
 
'Selecionamos nossa planilha resultados
Set ws = Worksheets("resultados")
 
'Criamos nosso objeto de requisção e enviamos
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")




For P = 1 To 100

'Url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
Url = "https://farmbox.cc/api/v1/applications?page=" & P

objHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False
objHTTP.Send
strResult = objHTTP.responseText
json = strResult
 
Set objetoJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)
 
'Criamos as células de cabeçalho
ws.Cells(1, 1) = "nome"
ws.Cells(1, 2) = "link"
 
'Fazemos um loop na propriedade results da resposta da API
i = 2 'Começaremos o contador na linha 2
For Each pAplicacao In objetoJson("applications")
    lfin = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Cells(lfin + 1, 1) = pAplicacao("id")
    ws.Cells(lfin + 1, 2) = pAplicacao("code")
    ws.Cells(lfin + 1, 3) = pAplicacao("applied_unit")
    
    
    i = i + 1
Next
 
Next
 
End Sub
```